# I am trying to install new version of Ruby, but still see old gems, why?

Tags: ruby, windows

My previous installation was messed up. So I renamed my ruby directory into rubyBad, and ran WindowsInstaller again, to install into a virgin Ruby200-x64 directory.  Still, when I go to

> F:\ruby\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems

I see a whole lot of gems, including Rails. Why is that? And how do I uninstall Ruby cleanly?

Comment: Do you have rvm installed for windows? That can help clear up a lot of gem madness

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow there is no rvm for windows

Comment: Yeah, there is tik on windows, but it is my understanding that it does not do much. Was considering running Ruby on Cygwin, but it still does not have Ruby 2.0 for some reason. Bummer!

Comment: have you use rvm/rbenv?

Comment: Did you re-install into the same directory? The installer probably left the `gems` directory alone since it had content that wasn't originally added by the installer. You can just delete the `F:\ruby\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems` directory and that will cleanly remove all the gems.

Comment: The only reason why just deleting `F:\ruby\Ruby200-x64` wouldn't be a clean uninstall is that there might be some environment variables that would be left in-place from the previous install.

Comment: @ТаняТ. cygwin may have only supported Ruby 1.9 because it was the "long term service" type of branch. It lost extended support February 2015. I believe cygwin supports Ruby 2.1 now. Are you still having this issue?